# undefined method `vote_for_song_songs_path' [rails 4]

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4

So, I'm having trouble getting the [Thumbs Up gem](https://rubygems.org/gems/thumbs_up) workin'.

I've followed [this tutorial](http://rails-learning.blogspot.ca/2012/01/implementing-thumbsup-gem-in-rails.html) but I seem to be getting the below errror:

**Error msg:**

```
NoMethodError in Songs#index

Showing /Users/apane/Downloads/leap_stage/leap_stage/app/views/songs/index.html.erb where line #10 raised:

undefined method `vote_for_song_songs_path' for #<#<Class:0x007fd0b60203d0>:0x007fd0b26ecdc0>

<li><%= link_to song.title, song %><br></li>
Submitted <%= time_ago_in_words(song.created_at) + " ago" %>
<span class="comments"> | <%= pluralize(song.comments.size, 'comment') %></span><br />
<%=link_to image_tag('thumbs_up', :border => 0), vote_for_song_songs_path(@song), :remote => true %>
<%=link_to image_tag('thumbs_down', :border => 0), vote_against_song_songs_path(@song), :remote => true %>
```

**index.html.erb**

```
<div id="layout1">

<h3>Songs</h3>

<ol>
<% @songs.each do |song| %>
 <li><%= link_to song.title, song %><br></li>
    Submitted <%= time_ago_in_words(song.created_at) + " ago" %>
    <span class="comments"> | <%= pluralize(song.comments.size, 'comment') %></span><br />
 <%=link_to image_tag('thumbs_up', :border => 0), vote_for_song_songs_path(@song), :remote => true %>
 <%=link_to image_tag('thumbs_down', :border => 0), vote_against_song_songs_path(@song), :remote => true %>


<%#= link_to 'Show', song, class: "button small secondary" %>
<%= link_to('Edit', edit_song_path(song), class: "button small secondary") if can? :update, @song %>
<%= link_to('Destroy', song, method: :delete, data: {confirm: 'Are you sure?'}, class: "button small secondary") if can? :destroy, @song %>


<% end %>

</ol>
</div>


<br />
</div>
```

**song_controller.rb**

```
class SongsController < ApplicationController
  before_filter :authenticate_user!, only: [:create ,:edit, :update, :destroy, :vote_for_song]
  before_action :set_song, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy, :vote_for_song]


  def vote_for_song
      @song = Song.find(params[:id])
      current_user.vote_for(@song)
      respond_to do |format|
        format.js
      end
  end

  def vote_against_song
    @song = Song.find(params[:id])
    current_user.vote_against(@song)
    respond_to do |format|
      format.js
    end
  end


  # GET /Songs
  # GET /Songs.json
  def index
    @songs = Song.all
  end

  # GET /Songs/1
  # GET /Songs/1.json
  def show
   @comment = Comment.new(song: @song)
  end

  # GET /Songs/new
  def new
    @song = Song.new
  end

  # GET /Songs/1/edit
  def edit
  end

  # POST /Songs
  # POST /Songs.json
  def create
    @song = Song.new(song_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @song.save
        format.html { redirect_to @song, notice: 'Song was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render action: 'show', status: :created, location: @song }
      else
        format.html { render action: 'new' }
        format.json { render json: @song.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # PATCH/PUT /Songs/1
  # PATCH/PUT /Songs/1.json
  def update
    respond_to do |format|
      if @song.update(song_params)
        format.html { redirect_to @song, notice: 'Song was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { head :no_content }
      else
        format.html { render action: 'edit' }
        format.json { render json: @song.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # Song /Songs/1
  # Song /Songs/1.json
  def destroy
    @song.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to songs_url }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end

  private

    def set_song
       @song = Song.find(params[:id])
     end

     def song_params
       params.require(:song).permit(:title, :artist, :bio, :track, :user_id)
     end
  end
```

**song.rb**

```
class Song < ActiveRecord::Base

  acts_as_voteable

  belongs_to :user
  has_many :comments, :dependent => :destroy


has_attached_file :track,
                  :url  => "/assets/songs/:id/:style/:basename.:extension",
                  :path => ":rails_root/public/assets/songs/:id/:style/:basename.:extension"


  validates_attachment :track, :presence => true

  validates :title, length: { minimum: 10 }
  validates :bio, length: { maximum: 300 }



end
```

**user.rb**

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :token_authenticatable, :confirmable,
  # :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable

  has_many :songs
  has_many :comments

  acts_as_voter

end
```

**vote.rb**

```
class Vote < ActiveRecord::Base

  scope :for_voter, lambda { |*args| where(["voter_id = ? AND voter_type = ?", args.first.id, args.first.class.base_class.name]) }
  scope :for_voteable, lambda { |*args| where(["voteable_id = ? AND voteable_type = ?", args.first.id, args.first.class.base_class.name]) }
  scope :recent, lambda { |*args| where(["created_at > ?", (args.first || 2.weeks.ago)]) }
  scope :descending, lambda { order("created_at DESC") }

  belongs_to :voteable, :polymorphic => true
  belongs_to :voter, :polymorphic => true

  attr_accessible :vote, :voter, :voteable if ActiveRecord::VERSION::MAJOR < 4


  # Comment out the line below to allow multiple votes per user.
  validates_uniqueness_of :voteable_id, :scope => [:voteable_type, :voter_type, :voter_id]

end
```

**routes.rb**

```
Leap2::Application.routes.draw do

  resources :comments

  devise_for :users, controllers: {registrations: 'registrations'}
  resources :songs


  get '/contact', to: 'songs#contact'
  get '/faq', to: 'songs#faq'

  root to: 'songs#index'
  end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you need an :id param, it should be get or put, and to avoid writing "song_songs" you can do

```
resources :songs do
  member do
    get :vote_for, :vote_against
  end
end
```

That gets vote_for_song_path(@song) and vote_against_song_path(@song). Technically it would be more correct to have `put :vote_for`, since it's not an idempotent request, but then you'd need to remember to put `method: :put` at the end of your url.

Edit: to get the number of votes to show up, put an element in the page like

```
<span class="votes"><%= pluralize(song.votes.count, 'Vote') %></span>
```

right after the similar comments span. Also, since you have the `vote_for_song_path` called remotely, you'll want to update the page with js, which means you need to be able to find the spot on the page that has the number of votes for a song. Do do that, replace the `<li>` with

```
<%= content_tag_for :li, song do %>
   [then put everything in your view that has to do with one song in the block]
<% end %>
```

That will generate html like `<li id="song_21" class="song">...`, which you can refer to in an update_votes.js.erb template,

```
$("#song_<%= @song.id %> .votes").html("<%= pluralize(song.votes.count, "Vote") %>")
```

That will send javascript to your view to update the proper element; you just have to instruct the controller to send it. I believe

```
format.js { render 'update_votes' }
```

in both the vote_for and vote_against actions will do it.

Comment: did that, now i'm getting: undefined method `vote_for_song_songs_path'

Comment: right, because the method can now just be written as `vote_for_song_path`, not `vote_for_song_songs_path`.

Comment: thanks my man, one last thing now when I click thumbs up or thumbs down it seems to be working but do you know how I can show the number of votes?

Comment: The solution is long enough I'm going to edit my answer for it.